# Getting some data from a PHP (json_encode) and now need to access it within the javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json, xui

I am currently using Phonegap and XUI to create web app.

I am retrieving some data from an external domain using a http request via XUI.

This is working correctly and I receive the JSON data back correctly, see the data format below:

```
({"first":"John","last":"Smith","HighScore":"75"})
```

So now I want to be able to access the individual assets of the data using javascript.

```
 x$('#test').xhr(URL,function() {
    loggedin = this.responseText; // This is the data that has been received from the PHP file
    if(loggedin != '1') // If not 1 then will let them in
    {
        alert(loggedin); // Alerts with the data recieved
    }
    else // Login incorrect
    {alert('Sorry you login details were incorrect please try again.');}
});
```

I know its probably simple to do but I just can't seem to figure it out so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Kane

Answer (score 1):

JSON object accessor syntax is `object.key`, so if `this.responseText` is `{"first":"John","last":"Smith","HighScore":"75"}` then you'd display `Smith` with `this.responseText.last`

An example usage for your alert could be:

```
alert('Hello ' + this.responseText.first + ' ' this.responseText.last + '! You currently have a high score of ' + this.responseText.HighScore + ' points! Play again!');
```

Comment: I had previously tried this as when I have used done it in the past this was the method.|
I tried `alert(this.responseText.highscore);` but came up 'undefined'.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's case sensitive. It would be `this.responseText.HighScore` -- Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mm9rc/